# Can an SVG be scaled smaller than its viewbox?

Tags: mobile, svg

Can you scale an SVG to dimensions smaller than its viewbox without changing the dimensions of the viewbox?

`<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1365 767" enable-background="new 0 0 1365 767" xml:space="preserve">`

Comment: A viewBox is just the co-ordinate system for the contents. It is unconnected to the size unless you omit the width or height when it might be used as a fallback.

Comment: Noted. I omitted the width and height, but the svg will not shrink down to smart phone size.